# Identify brand of these non-LEGO parts

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I bought a bulk of bricks, some of them are not LEGO, but the quality is perfect - gloss, fit, plates have groove, transparent parts are clear.

I would like to know which brand also produces such nice bricks.

There are only numbers at the bottom:

- 15012-02
- 15111-01
- 15113-01
- 15116-01
- 15425-01

The fact that there are such small numbers molded proves about the good quality.

[image]

Comment: Not positive, but these could be produced by the [Oxford](http://oxfordtoy.co.kr/index.asp) toy company. They make very convincing clones for their own lines and a number of other companies.

Comment: Might also be [Sluban](https://www.sluban.nl/en).